# Best practice for showing more options in an Android application

Tags: forms, android

There's a form and the usual action is to fill out the form and submit it to the next level; but there are other actions that can be taken, such as:

- adding other people to view and edit this form,
- or adding rows (which leads to adding additional data fields to the form).

**How I show these additional options without complicating the form, and make extra options easy to find and use?**

I considered two possible options, but I can't decide which is better.

1. Put the additional options in a "more" menu in the app bar (the three dots icon).
2. Use a call to action for submit and a ghost button for "more options", and clicking on the "more options" button leads to adding two more buttons for adding people or adding rows (which doesn't seem to be visually appealing as the page ends up showing 4 buttons after clicking on the more options, but easier to find and use).

Any other ideas on how to do this will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any example layouts you can share? What type of layout is the current form? Is it a full-screen activity or a dialog?

Comment: In this scenario, can a user submit the form and then 'add people'?

Comment: @AdityaDurgude No, the people added to this form according to their level of authority can edit the form.

Answer (score 3):

Considering you have a little space below the submit button. Think of doing this:

**The additional options will behave as secondary actions**. Try placing the links in vertical order, or above the Submit button and see which option works better.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response :). But again it's on android, which kinds of buttons do you think is appropriate to use in this case on android? Is it ok to use material flat buttons? (using material flat buttons for more options and a call to action for submit, it's somehow too much, what you showed in the picture is great when it's on web)
Also there's this issue that, though these two actions are not usual, but I don't want it to become hard to find these actions for the user. Don't you think this way the user may not see the options?

Answer (score 1):

Material guidelines has a component that might help you: [Expansion panels](https://material.io/guidelines/components/expansion-panels.html#)

It is a collapsed panel that displays summary information. Upon selecting the collapsed panel, it expands to display the full expansion panel.

Here is an example how you can implement it (check the "more options" button):

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fboY44.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend you don't have too many non-primary options when it comes to an action-heavy activity/page.

`Adding people to edit`

Rather than giving this option while filling out the form, provide it once the form is submitted.

Once **SUBMIT** is clicked, show the user the option with a text like,

"Congrats! Your form is successfully submitted. You can make this form available to others `for viewing and editing`"

(the last part may or may not be explicitly mentioned).

`Adding rows`

Please be specific as to what this means. Like **Add alternate number** or **Link Facebook** account.

Never leave ambiguous Call To Actions that make the user guess.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the form should be available to be edited before submission, people may have different authorities and so they may just compose a form but don't have the authority to submit it.

Comment: Also adding rows has a clear meaning here and I don't think it would be confused with anything... It's kinda like a dataset and adding row has a specific meaning.